# Multiple UNWIND statements causing wrong output in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I am running this cypher query on Neo4j

```
match x = (t1:Team)-[ho: Home]->(g: Game)<-[aw: Away]-(t2: Team)
with t1.name as tname1, 
     sum(toInteger(substring(g.full_time,0,1)) - 
     toInteger(substring(g.full_time,2,2))) as tgoals1, 
     t2.name as tname2, 
     sum(toInteger(substring(g.full_time,2,2))- 
     toInteger(substring(g.full_time,0,1))) as tgoals2
unwind [tgoals1 , tgoals2] as tgoals
unwind [tname1 , tname2] as tname
return tname
```

It gives output like this

```
"Arsenal FC"
"Leicester City FC"
"Arsenal FC"
"Leicester City FC"
"Brighton & Hove Albion FC"
"Manchester City FC"
"Brighton & Hove Albion FC"
"Manchester City FC"
```

While actually the output should be like this

```
"Arsenal FC"
"Leicester City FC"
"Brighton & Hove Albion FC"
"Manchester City FC"
```

If I remove the line

```
unwind [tgoals1 , tgoals2] as tgoals
```

Output becomes alright, but what I actually want is

```
return tname, tgoals
```

So I can't remove it.
In short, the two `UNWIND` statements work fine individually, but when I put them both together, this problem of repetition occurs. 
Can anyone please tell me why is it happening and how can I fix this?

Comment: It is hard to debug your query without a sample data to work with. Please give us sample data then we can help you. For immediate fix you can do:  WITH DISTINCT tname as tname after UNWIND.  However, it is better to find the root cause of the duplication.

Comment: This is the [file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1srYULNrvZzSz54zAHBV-QYIFn8Bktvaz) and this is the [query](http://freetexthost.com/wt6eyhcmns) to ingest data. And I can not put distinct because for every record of `tname`, there is a record of `tgoals` which I want to aggregate later.

Comment: So what is your expected result for return tname, tgoals?

Comment: The first row will be like `Arsenal FC,1`, 2nd will be `Leicester City FC, -1`, third will be `Brighton & Hove Albion FC,-2` and 4th will be `Manchester City FC, 2`...basically it's the goal difference (column `FT`) for every team in every match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your data and load statement. It was easier for me to play around with the data and come up with a solution.  Basically, I collected home teams and the goals then combine it with away team for the same game and get the goals.  I put an order by id so that I can manually check the correctness of the result but you can remove it if you want.

Notes:
The source of duplication is from the line where we get the tgoals. Each Home and Away teams each will have two values because we compute it on the same path (x). So we get like Home, 1 , -1 . Away -1, 1. When you unwind it separately, it will assign 1 and -1 to Home and 1 and -1 to Away. So to fix this duplication, we created a pair (called a list) Home, tgoal and Away tgoal.  In this way, we only get one tgoal for Home and one tgoal for Away. I call this dictionary (tname, tgoal) as combo. It is "collected" by getting all home teams and their goals, then add away teams and their goals. Once you have them in one collection, call the first element c[0] as team and the second element as goals. Cypher is like python wherein the first element of a list has index 0.

```
match (t1:Team)-[ho: Home]->(g: Game)
with t1.name as tname1, ID(g) as id1,
     toInteger(substring(g.full_time,0,1)) -
     toInteger(substring(g.full_time,2,2)) as tgoals1
match (t2:Team)-[aw: Away]->(g)
where ID(g) = id1
with tname1, tgoals1, t2.name as tname2, ID(g) as id2,
     collect ([tname1, tgoals1]) + collect([t2.name, toInteger(substring(g.full_time,2,2)) -
     toInteger(substring(g.full_time,0,1))]) as combo
unwind combo as c
return  c[0] as tname, c[1] as tgoals
order by id2
```

Result: (sample)

```
╒═══════════════════════════╤════════╕
│"tname"                    │"tgoals"│
╞═══════════════════════════╪════════╡
│"Arsenal FC"               │1       │
├───────────────────────────┼────────┤
│"Leicester City FC"        │-1      │
├───────────────────────────┼────────┤
│"Brighton & Hove Albion FC"│-2      │
├───────────────────────────┼────────┤
│"Manchester City FC"       │2       │
├───────────────────────────┼────────┤
│"Chelsea FC"               │-1      │
├───────────────────────────┼────────┤
│"Burnley FC"               │1       │
├───────────────────────────┼────────┤
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you help me understand what `collect` statements are doing here?